# Specific day or holiday in materialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, materialize

is possible to make a specific day for example a holiday using materializecss?

if I use jqueryUI using `'beforeShowDay'`. The step is I will call a function inside `beforeShowDay` function, return the status of date (event or holiday), add another condition and change the CSS.

here is an example https://codepen.io/mohitbhansali/pen/NPxzYq

My question is how to create holiday in materializecss? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Materialize you can use `events` option and add an array of dates that you want to highlight.

Days format must be `eee mmm dd yyyy`. After this materialize add an `has-event` class to the date and you can use it to highlight date with css.

Assume you want to highlight all sundays of august as holiday :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      events: ["Sun Aug 05 2018",
               "Sun Aug 12 2018",
               "Sun Aug 19 2018",
               "Sun Aug 26 2018"
              ]
      });
});
```

Here is complete example : [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bahmanparsamanesh/o68yjwm0/1/)

Comment: Your welcome. For more info, take a look at options table here : https://materializecss.com/pickers.html

Comment: How did you figure out that Materialize adds a `has-event` class to the `events` dates? This looks undocumented.